# Get NSData from assets-library URL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get NSData from mp4 file from device library.

This link look like this:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=32515720-939A-456F-958F-0B2F397416EB&ext=mp4
```

I've tried this code:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc((NSUInteger)rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)rep.size error:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

But `defaultRepresentation` deprecated in iOS 9.

I've also tried `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:url];` but it returns nil.

Comment: deprecated != not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire class of of `ALAsset` is deprecated in iOS 9. You should now consider using `PHAsset` instead. There is a API to get the `PHAsset` from the old asset url `ALAsset`. See the [following](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAsset/fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:):

> The Assets Library framework is deprecated in iOS 8.0 and later, replaced by the Photos framework. Use this method if your app has previously stored URLs from ALAsset objects and you need to retrieve the corresponding Photos framework objects.

```
+ (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs
                                                 options:(PHFetchOptions *)options
```

And then you could use the following [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:) in `PHImageManager` to get the `NSData` of the `PHAsset`:

```
- (PHImageRequestID)requestImageDataForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset
                                     options:(PHImageRequestOptions *)options
                               resultHandler:(void (^)(NSData *imageData,
                                                       NSString *dataUTI,
                                                       UIImageOrientation orientation,
                                                       NSDictionary *info))resultHandler
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:
1. Request Asset from Photos Library
2. Request Data from Asset
3. Return block

```
   func getDataFromAssetAtUrl( assetUrl: URL, success: @escaping (_ data: NSData) -> ()){
    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetUrl], options: nil)
    if let phAsset = fetchResult.firstObject {
        PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: phAsset, options: nil) {
            (imageData, dataURI, orientation, info) -> Void in
            if let imageDataExists = imageData {
                success(imageDataExists as NSData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example use:

```
import Photos //this on top of your file

open func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let assetUrl = assetDataFromMediaInfo(info: info)!
        getDataFromAssetAtUrl(assetUrl: assetUrl) { (dataOfAsset) in
            //TODO do something with NSData
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great answer! You might want to consider showing the implementation of `assetDataFromMediaInfo` for completeness. Thanks!